# C#: Is it possible to get the Exception trigger?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch

I have a function with a `try`-`catch` block. When I run the solution on localhost, it doesn't throw an exception. But when I run it on the server, I sometimes get the exception message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

The `catch` block in my code looks like this:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Mailing.SendMail(@gmail.com,
        e.Message + Environment.NewLine + Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString);
}
```

Whenever an exception is caught, I want to send an email.

My question is: can I get the trigger parameter or line from the exception?

Comment: You could simply send `e.ToString()` instead of `e.Message` to include the stack trace.

Comment: Better yet, enable `Break On All Exceptions`.  This is actually a duplicate of other NullReferenceException questions

Comment: In fact, posting `Exception.ToString()` results is a *requirement* if you want to get a quick answer in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about obtaining data from exception?

1. `e.StackTrace` - stack trace
2. `e.Message` - user friendly info
3. `e.Data` - additional data (may be null)

To get line number, you can use:

```
StackTrace st = new StackTrace(ex, true);
StackFrame frame = st.GetFrame(0);
int line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
```

Comment: Exception.ToString() will return all of these. No need to call each individually

Comment: Yes, but if he wanted to use it somehow different, this is more flexible.

Comment: This is more work and prone to errors. If you want to log something, just log the exception. If you want to ask about exceptions in StackOverflow, just post `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: Also, this won't show any inner exceptions. Eg, tasks wrap actuall exceptions in an `AggregateException`, libraries typically wrap detailed exceptions in a high level exception. `Exception.ToString()` walks the entire exception tree